# App made from PhoneGap forces user to log out when choosing image

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap

When a user logs in. And chooses an image. It successfully uploads the image. BUT when a new user logs in and chooses an image, the user get logout by force. I've been surfing the web for this problem, but I can't find a proper answer. I've used localStorage for log in and removes the localStorage item whe they log out.

```html
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="file-field input-field container col-s12">
      <div class="form-group group">
        <div class="btn">
          <span><i class="fa fa-camera"></i> Upload Image</span>
          <input type="file" name="file" accept='image/*'>
        </div>
        <div class="file-path-wrapper">
          <input class="file-path validate" type="text" name="file" accept='image/*'>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```js
var form = $(this);
var form_data = new FormData(form[0]);

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: upload.php,
  data: form_data ? form_data : form.serialize(),
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(data) {
  }
```

Comment: And how should we know what happens? What have you tried to debug the problem? The given code itself does not check for any logins, neither does it perform a logout

Comment: I've used localStorage to save the data of user when they log in. And remove the item in localStorage when they logged out.

Comment: Still, there is no code given that provides more information about how that logout happens. Is it triggered by the backend you are posting to? And if something happens in localstorage, is there any more code involved?

Comment: Found out what the problem is! The problem occurs when I choose from the gallery of my phone. But when I choose from recent, downloads, etc. it works perfectly fine. I still want to debug it tho.